# Where can negation happen in participle phrases? Are both correct? "Not having heard the news…" and "Having not heard the news…"

Tags: word-order, negation, participles

To negate a participle phrase we use **not** at the beginning of it, as in
"**Not** having heard the news, he had no idea what was going on."
Can we also use the negative particle in some other porition in the sentence  without it making any change in the meaning of the sentence? As in "Having **not** heard the news, he had no idea what was going on."
Is it entirely wrong or is it used in spoken English by native speakers (even as a common mistake among native speakers of English)?

Comment: They're both fine because they both go in appropriate places for a negative: at the beginning of the participle verb phrase, **or** after the first auxiliary verb in the verb phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both sound fine to me (I use and hear both often).

The second version "Having not heard ..." is, to my ears, a little more emphatic (that you really didn't hear the news).